# Estimating finite sample bias for Instrumental Variables

Tags: r, regression, instrumental-variables

Are there ways to ***estimate*** the finite sample bias with instrumental variables? I guess this would be conditional on assuming some structure to the problem and also would involve simulation, but, at least in applied econometrics papers, I have never seen people do it.

*PS: If possible, the answer could be illustrated with R code.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the model with one regressor and many instruments(vector-matrix notation)
$$y = x\beta +u$$
$$x = Z\gamma  +v$$

[Bound, Jaeger & Baker  (1995)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2291055) give the following approximation to the 2SLS finite sample bias:

$$B(\hat \beta_{IV}) = \frac {\operatorname{Cov}(u,v)}{\gamma'Z'Z\gamma}(K-2)$$

where $K$ is the number of instrument (the column dimension of matrix Z). Naturally, one uses the estimated quantities to calculate the above. This as a special case of results in [A.L.Nagar (1959)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1909352).
Other relevant literature  is [A.Buse (1992)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2951682) and [Staiger and Stock (1997)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2171753).